# Error: IO::Pipe: Cannot exec: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, perl, ubuntu, io, cpan

I'm new to Docker and Perl.
I want to dockerize my perl application but I get following error at runtime:

```
Error: IO::Pipe: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y libimage-magick-perl && \
    apt install -y make && \
    apt install -y gcc && \
    apt install -y perl && \
    apt install -y cpanminus
   
RUN cpan install YAML
RUN cpan install IPC::Run
    
WORKDIR /opt
COPY . /opt/deploy

ENTRYPOINT ["perl", "/opt/deploy/bin/deploy"]
```

This is the file where I use the IO::Pipe module:

```
package Deployment::Log::File;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Tie::Handle';

use constant TRUE  => (1 == 1);
use constant FALSE => (0 == 1);

use Fcntl qw(:flock);
use IO::File;
use IO::Pipe;
use Symbol;
use Sys::Hostname;
use Text::ParseWords;
use Time::HiRes;

...
my $class       = shift;  $class = ref($class) if ref($class);
my $destination = shift;
my $layout      = shift;

my $handle;

if ($destination =~ s/^\s*\|\s*//) {
  my @token = map { $class->interpolate($_) } Text::ParseWords::shellwords($destination);

$handle = IO::Pipe->new;
$handle->writer(@token)
  or return undef;
```

I tried to install IO::Pipe and IO with cpan and cpanm but nothing worked. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Probably going to need to see some code.

Comment: I assume you checked that /opt/deploy/bin/deploy, /opt and /opt/deploy exists and has the correct permissions?

Comment: @TLP Can you quickly tell how to do it in a docker environment?

Comment: @TLP I checked it but /opt/deploy/bin/deploy in no directory this is my script which I run

Comment: @Soteri I don't know Docker, I was just using common sense, if it is missing a directory, and you have supplied a directory, maybe check if that directory is really there

Comment: @Soteri Are you able to install the `IO` module from the `Dockerfile` ? Please provide a minimal Perl script that reproduces the error, see [mcve] for more information

Comment: You don't show what the token array is set to. It is most likely that the error is that command-line specified by token can't be executed because the command doesn't exist

Comment: Re "*I tried to install IO::Pipe and IO with cpan and cpanm but nothing worked.*", The message comes from IO::Pipe, so IO::Pipe is installed. That is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`$token[0]` is expected to contain the name of a program to run. It can either be a path or a simple file name (which the kernel resolves to a path using the `PATH` env var).

Either you provided a simple file name, and no executable file with that name is found in the any directories specified by the `PATH` env var, or you provided a path to a non-existent file.

Perhaps the program makes incorrect assumptions about its current work directory?